XGBoost Tree Plots in mlr3
I'm trying to get a plot of a single tree from an XGboost model fit in mlr3, and I can't seem to find any examples. I know there's a way using the underlying xgboost (see here), which mlr3 calls, but I can't find any ways to pull out the structure of the trees from an mlr3 model.
As an example:
#XGBoost tree plotting example

data(iris) #Iris dataset
sppNum <- as.numeric(iris$Species)-1 #Species as numeric (0-3), required for multiclass predictions

#Testing/training indices
set.seed(1)
testID <- as.vector(sapply(0:2,function(x) sort(sample(1:50,10,replace = FALSE)+(x*50)))) 
trainID <- which(!1:150 %in% testID)

# XGboost example ---------------------------------------------------------

library(xgboost)
library(DiagrammeR)
#Make testing/training datasets
datTrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=as.matrix(iris[trainID,1:4]),label=sppNum[trainID]) 
datTest <- xgb.DMatrix(data=as.matrix(iris[testID,1:4]),label=sppNum[testID])
watchlist <- list(train = datTrain, eval = datTest)

#Parameter list
parList <- list(max_depth = 3, eta = 1, verbose = 0, nthread = 1,
                objective = "multi:softmax", eval_metric = "auc", num_class=3)
xgbMod <- xgb.train(parList, datTrain, nrounds = 100, watchlist) #Fit model

xgb.plot.tree(model = xgbMod, trees = 1) #Plot single tree


# mlr3 example ------------------------------------------------------------

library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3viz)

data(iris)

tsk_mlr3 <- as_task_classif(iris,target='Species') #Set up task
#Set up learner
lrn_mlr3 <- lrn('classif.xgboost',nrounds=100,max_depth = 3, eta = 1,
                eval_metric='auc') 
lrn_mlr3$train(tsk_mlr3,row_ids = trainID) #Train learner on subset
lrn_mlr3$predict(tsk_mlr3,row_ids = testID) #Predict

xgb.plot.tree(lrn_mlr3$model, trees=1) #Displays the following error:
#Error in xgb.plot.tree(lrn_mlr3$model, trees = 1) : 
#  model: Has to be an object of class xgb.Booster

Is there any way to plot (at least one) of the trees from XGboost in mlr3?

When you say that it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean?

@LarsKotthoff it displays an error message. I've updated the code example to show this.

The issue is just that you need to specify model= this code works for me.
xgb.plot.tree(model = lrn_mlr3$model, trees=1)

I tried debugonce(xgb.plot.tree) and found the model argument was NULL so it failed a check on inheriting from xgb.Booster.
